# iphone SDK: View generate without IB spacing problem

Tags: iphone

I generate a ViewController / View in my window based application.
It will show directly at startup, it works, no problem.

But on the buttom, the View has Space left, its exactly the space the status bar needs on the top, so I think I must put my View under the status bar, not behind it.

How to do?

Code:

```
StartViewController *a = [[StartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"bla"];
[self setStartViewController:a];
[a release];
[window addSubviewl:[StartViewController view]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is either not high enough, or your upper left corner doesn't account for the statusbar, i.e. (0,20).

Comment: I think the last one is the problem, because the label I set up vor the View in the IB, isnt in the position when I start the application.

how to chance the left corner for status bar?

Comment: I thought you build that view programmatically ("without IB") - if you use IB to configure you should examine your nib/xib and experiment with the frame and autoresizing. IIRC there is the option for status bar somewhere.